# Using the microphone for iOS apps built in forge

Tags: ios, microphone, trigger.io, forge

Does Forge (trigger.io) provide APIs to access the microphone in iOS devices? If yes, it would be great if someone can point me to an example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

we have a story for an API for audio capture in our current sprint, actually. Scheduled for completion by the end of the month!

Comment: Also searching for this, looking forward to it :)